# Launching multiple turtlebots under namespaces (real environment)

Tags: ros, navigation, namespaces, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to launch multiple turtlebots (each under a namespace) with navigation stack. I am building upon the similar task for stage simulator [(link)](https://github.com/gergia/multiple_turtlebots_stage_amcl). As a first step, I try to launch a single turtlebot under namespace.

Currently, the attempt to launch a single robot under namespace with amcl failed. The tf tree looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11955498/framesTurtlebotUnderNamespace.pdf). The link between */map* and *robot_0/odom* is missing. Amcl should be publishing this connection.
The messages from console are following:

- */robot_0/amcl: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1462444802.174762 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /robot_0/scan topic.*  : checked, data is being published at /robot_0/scan
- */robot_0/amcl: MessageFilter [target=robot_0/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.* : **This might be the key message**. If I set the logger level to debug, I see something like  *Added message in frame /camera_depth_frame at time 1462446392.094, count now 100*.
   I guess the trouble is that it is using frame id /camer_depth_frame (the absolute one) instead of one relative to the namespace (*robot_0 in this case*). I don't know how to fix it. I tried with using *openni2_tf_prefix.launch*, but doesn't help.
- */robot_0/move_base_node: Timed out waiting for transform from robot_0/base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101826 timeout was 0.1* : I guess this one is just a consequence of previous ones.

As I see this question being asked around, but without a complete solution, I created a [git repository](https://github.com/gergia/multiple_turtlebots_real_world) with the current code. I hope once I manage to solve this problem - with your help - to have the complete solution in the repository for the others to have use of it afterwards as well. Feel free to answer here, or experiment directly in the code (and let us know about any successful or even unsuccessful trials).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233674/launching-multiple-turtlebots-under-namespaces-(real-environment)/) by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 526 on 2016-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was is solved in [the repository](https://github.com/gergia/multiple_turtlebots_real_world).

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-09**:
This answer would be much more helpful if you wrote what you did to solve the errors that you got instead of just linking to a GitHub repository.

**Comment by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on 2020-02-10**:
Hello, I am from the year 2020. I've come back to tell you that jayess is right. Your answer is poo.